# Cutting back of pedestal

Tags: porcelain

We have poorly fitting pedestal sink in powder room, because the pedestal has hole in bottom that doesn’t line up with pipes coming through floor. Is there a way to cut away the bottom porcelain hole to make an entirely open horseshoe at bottom? This would allow a little play for pipes. 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you locked in to cutting the sink? Could you instead enlarge the hole in the floor and/or relocate or reroute the plumbing?

Answer (score 1):

Porcelain isn't terribly difficult to cut with the right abrasive tools, but you'd be left with a much more fragile base. Any bump by a rigid object is likely to crack it badly without that lateral support.

I'd definitely cut out only what's needed for your pipes and leave a substantial crossbeam at the rear.

Comment: Definitely much safer and easier to alter plumbing. Pain in the rear but a much better fix.